# Formualte the Lagrange dual $(D _1 )$ of $ (P _1 )$,

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

(a) One way to formulate the projection problem is
$$\min \frac{1}{2}\|x-a\|^2$$ $$s.t \> Ax=0$$
where $A$ is a matrix such that $L = \{x : Ax = 0\}$

(i) Formulate  the Lagrange dual $(D _1 )$ of $
(P _1 )$, and prove whether
strong duality between $(P _1 )$ and $(D_1 )$ holds.

Write down Lagrangian problem using Lagrange multipliers
$L(x,v)=\frac{1}{2}\|x-a\|^2+<Ax,v>$
Find Lagrange dual function
$\inf_{x}L(x,v)=\inf_{x}\{\frac{1}{2}\|x-a\|^2+<Ax,v>\}=\inf_{x}\{\frac{1}{2}<x-a,x-a>+<v,Ax>\}$
Find the Lagrange dual function

So I think I’m not understanding how to simply the above expression to

Comment: Compute the gradient w.r.t. to $x$. Substitute the value of $x$ in the function such that gradient will be zero.

Comment: $\nabla_x L = (x-a)+A^Tv$

Comment: But I thought you need to take the inf of the Lagrange function @Rajat

Comment: Yes. That is why you are minimizing. After substituting the $x$ in $L$ you will get the dual function and also remember $v \geq 0$ (element wise).